# Window frame specification in SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

I am running below code from the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#aggregate_window_functions) on SQLiteStudio 3.3.3 :

```
SELECT a, b, group_concat(b, '.') OVER (
  ORDER BY a ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
) AS group_concat FROM t1;
```

Where t1 is defined as :

```
CREATE TABLE t1(a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b, c);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES   (1, 'A', 'one'  ),
                        (2, 'B', 'two'  ),
                        (3, 'C', 'three'),
                        (4, 'D', 'one'  ),
                        (5, 'E', 'two'  ),
                        (6, 'F', 'three'),
                        (7, 'G', 'one'  );
```

Instead of getting the expected result as shown in the SQLite documentation I get :

| a | b | group_concat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | B | C |
| 3 | C | D |
| 4 | D | E |
| 5 | E | F |
| 6 | F | G |
| 7 | G |  |

How is this possible? Does this happen because I am using SQLiteStudio instead of SQLite? If this is the case, what are the rules for the frame definition of window functions in SQLiteStudio?

Comment: No, this is not possible. The documentation is correct.

Comment: Well, the docs are correct, but I get the same in SQLiteStudio. Weird. DB Browser for SQLite produces correct result. Both report SQLite 3.35.5.

Comment: It was a bug in SQLiteStudio 3.3.x. The upcoming version 3.4.0 has this fixed (you can download weekly build from GitHub Actions, if you have GitHub account).